# Are there any games which use Monero as money?

Tags: gaming, monero-based-economy

Are there any popular community games which are using Monero as money for its economy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not explicitly, no.

The closest example would be [CryptoKingdom](https://cryptokingdom.me/).  They use their own in-game currency, but I believe it's directly proportional to Monero supply and/or is easy to cash out with and transform into Monero.

Comment: The curency in use in millionths of a monero, so it's essentially monero. Similar to counting in cents instead of dollars. When you pay in, you pay monero. When you withdraw, you get monero.

Comment: It is called moneritos. Gold/CKG is something else, and not anchored to a monero/monerito value.

Answer (score 7):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but there's also monerodice.net where users can play dice and chat. Similarly there is the tippero bot on freenode in #monero and #tippero channels where users can play dice or blackjack with Monero.